# How do I apply CSS styling to a <div> block?

Tags: html, css

The following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Webpage</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the Heading of the webpage.</h1>
    .mainpara {background-color: #d3e5f2;}
    <div class="mainpara">
        <h3>And it will be the <strong>heading 2</strong>, main content body.</h3>
        <p>This is another body, composed of plain text. It's defined internally as a paragraph. Some style will be applied to this and the above heading 2 text by CSS applications.</p>
    </div>
    <h6>Note that this webpage designing enthusiasm was generated out of necessity for edition of the theme at <a href="http://japanaddicts.org/" target="_blank">Japanaddicts</a>, a website of <strong>cool people</strong> specialising in <em>Japanaddicting</em> others.
    <p style="color: #f60; font-size: 15px;">This is a line now. Yes another one. However, an inline CSS has been applied to it. This particular paragraph has a different style. It's troublesome, this inline CSS but it's experimental.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there's a "mainpara" division. How do I specifically apply styling to it? I tried `.mainpara {background-color: #d3e5f2;}`, as you can see. I also tried putting it above the  class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put CSS in a stylesheet, not as free text in the middle of your HTML.

Either use a style element or (preferably) put your CSS in an external file and reference it with a link element (both of which would go in the head, not the body).

There are examples of both [in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#html-tutorial)

Comment: But the other inline CSS styling worked, so that works for just <p>?

Comment: The other styling used a style attribute.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I'm also learning about external referencing, that's best, but for a test page I didn't think that much. So will something like this work:
<div style= stuff> content </div>?

Comment: Not if the stuff includes a selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .mainpara {background-color: #d3e5f2;}
</style>
```

you can not write css code in html page without using style tag

Comment: Thanks! This one worked too! However, I tried doing a <div style="background-color: #d3e5f2;"> and removed the class=mainpara and .mainpara thing. Both ways worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en-UK">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test Webpage</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!-- ALL STYLES SHOULD BE DEFINED HERE OR MOVED INTO A SEPERATE STYLE SHEET FILE THEN IMPORTED -->
    .mainpara {
    background-color: #d3e5f2;
    }
    <!-- Changes color and font size for all p tags on page -->
    p {
    color: #f60;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    <!-- Use an id for specific p tag -->
    #customParaStyleId {
    color: #f60;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    <!-- Use a class when you plan to apply it to many p tags on the same or additional pages -->
    .custParaStyleClass {
    color: #f60;
    font-size: 15px;
    }

    </style>

        </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is the Heading of the webpage.</h1>
        <!-- CLASSES ARE USED TO REPEAT STYLES ACROSS SITES -->
        <div class="mainpara">
            <h3>And it will be the <strong>heading 2</strong>, main content body.</h3>
            <p>This is another body, composed of plain text. It's defined internally as a paragraph. Some style will be applied to this and the above heading 2 text by CSS applications.</p>
        </div>
        <h6>Note that this webpage designing enthusiasm was generated out of necessity for edition of the theme at <a href="http://japanaddicts.org/" target="_blank">Japanaddicts</a>, a website of <strong>cool people</strong> specialising in <em>Japanaddicting</em> others.
<!-- USING ID AS EXAMPLE TO TARGET SPECIFIC SINGLE TAG -->
        <p id="customParaStyleId">This is a line now. Yes another one. However, an inline CSS has been applied to it. This particular paragraph has a different style. It's troublesome, this inline CSS but it's experimental.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS should be separated from the body of your HTML Code. It can be placed in either a separate style sheet that you import/include or it can appear between a `<style type="text/css"><!-- YOUR STYLES HERE--></style>` tags.

TIP:
Often I begin designing and manipulating styles in the head before separating them out into a style sheet. This allows me to focus on the design without having to worry about whether I attached the style sheet properly or not.

Once I finish the page I then move the working styles to a separate sheet to provide re-usable styles across the entire site.

Comment: Using classes and ids will become more important as you expand your site to include JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  .mainpara {background-color: #d3e5f2;}
</style>
```

If you have a stylesheet file or style.css you can just insert:

```
.mainpara {background-color: #d3e5f2;}
```

inside of the style.css file